# Error in download manager android

Tags: android, download, onresume, download-manager

Using Android Download Manager i am trying to implement multiple download of pdf files synchronously (ie,an instance of the request is generated after successful completion of the previous request),soon after a DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS notification in the broadcast receiver,a duplicate copy of the same request(with the same request id ) is generated and the DownlaodManager is initiated implicitly.For the second time the download fails,and DownlaodManager gives DownloadManager.status = ERROR CANNOT RESUME.Hence,pdf is not downloaded.This happens only when i try synchronized multiple download.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed that if you start another download immediately when current has finished, this error occurs. So, I solved this problem by inserting a sleep time in the current Thread between the finish and the start of the next download... I used Thread.sleep(1000), but you can try others values. (make sure you are not doing it in UIThread).
Works nice for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running your app on the Samsung device? I have the same problem with Nexus S, Galaxy Tab 10.1 and one which name I can't remember (they have Android versions 2.3.6, 3.2 and 4.0.4) but never on the HTC Nexus One, HTC Sensation (4.0.x) and HTC Explorer (2.3.5) or emulator.

I have this consequence:

```
06-05 17:42:26.756: INFO/DownloadManager(12113): Initiating request for download 1551
06-05 17:42:27.057: INFO/ololo(17021): Status for content://downloads/my_downloads/1551: file exists
06-05 17:42:27.137: INFO/DownloadManager(12113): Initiating request for download 1551
06-05 17:42:27.197: WARN/DownloadManager(12113): Aborting request for download 1551: Trying to resume a download that can't be resumed
06-05 17:42:27.247: WARN/ImageView(17021): Unable to open content: content://downloads/my_downloads/1551
```

I think this is very interesting problem.

[There](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18462) people say that this is Samsung and some other vendors issue. My solution is to implement my own DownloadManager or use someone's else.